# Disable Background stage javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm french, sorry for mistake.

I have an primary stage, and foreground an small second stage. I want to color in gray all the primary stage when the second stage is visible.

It's good, i cannot click in the primary stage with the line :

```
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
```

But I want to put a color gray in the primary stage. 
I try to disable all componant in the primary stage (every componant is gray and disable) but imageViews are not gray, it's a problem.

Help please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add all to a Stackpane and make a Region as a veil (visible=true/false).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VeilDemo extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // that is the veil
    Region veil = new Region();
    veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)");
    veil.setVisible(false);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Open Dialog");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
      Alert a = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
      //veil is only visible when alert window is showing
      veil.visibleProperty().bind(a.showingProperty());

      a.setContentText("The main window should be decorated with a veil.");
      a.setX(primaryStage.getX() + 200); // This is only for showing main window
      a.showAndWait();
    });

    Image img = new Image("https://www.gnu.org/graphics/gnu-head-sm.png");
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(img);

    // this should be the normal root of window
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(iv);
    bp.setBottom(btn);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(bp, veil);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

}
```

The main window will look like this:

[image: mainwindow]

and if the button was clicked, the info window opens and the veil is visibile on the main stage.

[image]